# error: The collection has not been initialized

Tags: list, javascript, caml

I get this error `error: The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.` it has a problem in `sp.runtime.js`

```
$(window).load(function () {

    jQuery("div#NBSinboxsent").find(".itemid").each(function () {
        var itemid = jQuery(this).text();

        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackRemove.removemessage(itemid));
    });
});
```

which then goes in to this :

```
NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackRemove = (function () {
    var listItemEnumeratorlistFeedback,
    collListItems;
    removemessage = function (getid) {

        NBSFeedbackEditInbox.siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/Community/News-and-feedback/Feedback';
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(NBSFeedbackEditInbox.siteURL);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Feedback Items');
        getid = getid.substring(getid.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
        getid = Math.round(getid);
        var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
query.set_viewXml("<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Integer'>"+getid+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
        collListItems = oList.getItems(query);
        clientContext.load(collListItems);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
    }
    onQuerySucceeded = function () {
        var itemTitle=[];
        listItemEnumeratorlistFeedback = collListItems.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumeratorlistFeedback.moveNext()) {

            feedbackListItem = listItemEnumeratorlistFeedback.get_current();
            itemTitle.push(feedbackListItem.get_item('Title'));
        }
        alert(itemTitle);
    }
```

I am trying to get an individual element that is a list given the id. The list is a set of folders in which are the items that I want to search to get the correct list item

There error is thrown just after collListItems.getEnumerator();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `clientContext.load(collListItems, 'Include(Title, Id)');`

You need to explicitly set the properties you need to load of the list item collection.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: clientContext.load(collListItems, 'Include(*)') How to do this ?